# Laravel 5.4 and Tymon JWT library: Token lifetime it is always only one minute

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, angular2-jwt

I have a problem using this library. The same code used on the client is the same one that runs on the server. The lifetime of the token is 1440 minutes, but this configuration only works on the local server, but not on the remote server.

I do not know if I should configure something else in the apache or in the system, but in Laravel exactly the same (I use git to send the changes). On both sides I work with Ubuntu 16.04, on my local server I use php 7.1 and in my remote server i use php 7.0. In my local browser I'm using Angular 4. My code in Laravel is:

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | JWT time to live
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the length of time (in minutes) that the token will be valid for.
    | Defaults to 1 hour
    |
    */

    'ttl' => 1440,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Refresh time to live
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the length of time (in minutes) that the token can be refreshed
    | within. I.E. The user can refresh their token within a 2 week window of
    | the original token being created until they must re-authenticate.
    | Defaults to 2 weeks
    |
    */
```

Answer (score 0):

When I uploaded the project I did it using github (I uploaded my project there) and the token configuration was in 1 minute of life. Although I modified the configuration in the config / jwt.php file so that the session lasted an entire day (1440 minutes) it did not work.

What I did was again upload the project to github (with the updated time to 1440 minutes) on a new project and this time it did work. This way I solved my problem.